# Можно ли получить массив checkbox которые находятся на определенной форме?

Tags: c#

Мне необходимо проверять какие `checkbox` включены.Суть в том что каждый `checkbox` несет собой определенное целое значение. И мне надо подсчитывать эти значения. У меня на форме их всего 5. Но если делать отдельную функцию для проверки это около 25 условий(если не больше). Подскажите можно ли как нибудь по хитрому это провернуть?Я думаю может как-нибудь через массив можно?

Comment: "около 25 условий(если не больше)" - ??

Comment: Тебе какую-то комбинаторику с них делать требуется?

Comment: Ну вообще checkbox - это либо 0, либо 1, он не сохраняет каких-то "целых значений".

Comment: @RomanIeromenko нет. Программа для тестирования. Я должен подсчитывать количество баллов за ответы с помощью checkboxов. Тоесть из БД парсятся вопросы,заносятся на форму. А чтобы выбрать ответы на них, нужно тыкать checkbox

Comment: Это winforms или wpf? Каким образом к чекбоксу привязывается целочисленное значение баллов?

Comment: @yolosora если мы нажали на чекбокс и нажали кнопку отправить данные, то в зависимости от вопроса плюсуется определенное количество баллов

Comment: @GnomSkull все ещё непонятно как связывается чекбокс с вопросом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю сделать с помощью рефлексии, где-то на форме организовать такой код:

```
var hh = this.GetType().GetFields().Where(ch=> ch.GetReflectedType() == typeof(CheckBox));
foreach (var item in hh) {
    var checker = hh as CheckBox;
    switch (checker != null && checker.Checked) {

      case true:
        //do smth
        break;
      case false:
        //do smth else
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

switch  — это оператор выбора, который выбирает для выполнения один раздел switch из списка кандидатов, сравнивая их с выражением соответствия.

```
 int caseSwitch = 1;

      switch (caseSwitch)
      {
          case 1:
              Console.WriteLine("Case 1");
              break;
          case 2:
              Console.WriteLine("Case 2");
              break;
          default:
              Console.WriteLine("Default case");
              break;
      }
```

Comment: что это значит?

Comment: Поясните плиз, как ваш ответ коррелирует с вопросом?

Comment: @tym32167 Если вопрос не подходит к ответу, это проблемы вопроса.

Comment: @Igor 42  ....:)